# can't detect cdrom drive

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, gentoo

I have an IDE dvd/cdrom drive on my computer that used to work with linux (basically every distro) and still works with the windows install. one day I noticed it stopped working and I have no idea why. It's been months and I've recomiled my kernel a few times, asked on gentoo forums, but nobody is able to figure it out.

Here are some pastes of important system information and if anybody is able to stop why my IDE cdrom/dvd rom drive doesn't have an associated device file I'll accept the answer.

- lspci -v: http://pastebin.com/f3991e382
- kernel config: http://pastebin.com/f49ec613d
- dmesg: http://pastebin.com/f7521350a
- /etc/fstab http://pastebin.com/f62bdcd6b
- /etc/group http://pastebin.com/f4b3507fc

I can post more information if needed.

thanks.

Comment: and where is the "add bounty" button?

Comment: It will be only available after a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the `00:06.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation CK804 IDE (rev f2) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])` with `00:07.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller (rev f3) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO]`: there is no `Kernel driver in use` string on the first. So the cause of the problem is absence of driver compiled in.

It is handled by `ide-cd` driver (at least on my machine) and is enabled by kernel config switch `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD`. Try searching for it in menuconfig (the '\' key) and enabling.

Also you will probably need a driver specific for your chipset: `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_AMD74XX`.

Comment: yep, pretty much what it looks like to me, too.  no IDE devices enumerated in dmesg, no driver loaded for the IDE chip.  i'll bet he could get libATA to handle it but that might require a recompile too.  IDE drivers might be an AMD74XX module or ide-generic (i believe ide-cd is layered on top of one of these).

Comment: That's AMD74XX: ide-generic will be enabled automatically.